# Create hot observable in Rx from array

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

How can I do this?

I have a code that does:

```
new int[]{1,2,3}.ToObservable().Subscribe(myObserver);
```

The problem is this first call is a cold observable so that on another call like this:

```
new int[]{4,5,6}.ToObservable().Subscribe(myObserver);
```

myObserver does not trigger onNext at all. Apparently because the first call publishes `1,2,3, END`. I don't want the observable to call "END", because I want to continue subscribing later on. Is there a function that easily does this for me?

Comment: Oh, BTQ, what you're asking for is not a "hot" observable. Your question title is a bit misleading.

Comment: BTW, BTQ was a typo for BTW. ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would need to do something like this:

```
new int[] { 1, 2, 3, }
    .ToObservable()
    .Concat(Observable.Never<int>())
    .Subscribe(myObserver); 

new int[] { 4, 5, 6, }
    .ToObservable()
    .Concat(Observable.Never<int>())
    .Subscribe(myObserver);
```

The key is to do a `.Concat(Observable.Never<int>())` on the observable to prevent it ever ending.

Comment: Thank you! That should do it.

Comment: @Alwyn - No worries. Just a quick warning - you need to make sure that you properly handle all exceptions as they will also end any observable too. If you need to filter out exceptions (which is often a bad idea) then take a look at `.Materialize()` & `.Dematerialize()`.

Comment: Probably no need to worry about errors if the user is actually getting arrays, and then turning them into Observable Sequences :)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how these observables are used in context, my first recommendation would be to `Concat` the two observables (or `IEnumerable`s) before subscribing.

```
(new int[]{1,2,3}.ToObservable())
.Concat(new int[]{4,5,6}.ToObservable())
.Subscribe(myObserver)
```

There is no method that I know of that you could insert between the `ToObservable` and `Subscribe` calls in your code to get the behavior you are after.  Such a method could be written, but it would not play well with the rest of the library.

Comment: Gideon, this is not an option with what I'm working on. I don't have both lists available to me at the same time, in fact they're in 2 separate areas of the code, and I'd hate to couple them.

Answer (score 1):

Fwiw, to make a Cold Observable into a Hot Observable, use Multicast:

```
var obs = new[] {1,2,3}.ToObservable()
    .Multicast(new Subject<int>())

// TODO: Subscribe as many people as you want

obs.Connect();  // Everyone subscribed gets 1,2,3,Completed now

obs.Subscribe(...);  // This guy gets no results
```